# Incorrectly Deleted User - user31385

Tags: support

My profile (user31385) has been deleted because someone has got the impression that I am under 13. I was born in 1964 and so however much I wish I was younger, I'm not underage for this community. How can I get that profile re-enabled please?

If not, perhaps the questions, answers and reputation I accumulated on that profile could be transferred to this one (user31570)? Whichever is the easiest.
Kind regards,
Robert Day.

Answer (score 11):

First off, thanks to reaching out to us to clarify this issue. We hate having to do these deletions, especially in edgy we're-not-so-sure cases, but they're required by law. Your profile was deleted because of this explicit statement that was made by you in chat:

> All this and I've still to see my 12th birthday! :D

While I can see how that statement might have been a playful joke, laws rarely allow us to *interpret* the statements for anything more than face value. And at face value, that statement is a clear admission to being under 12 years old, and we were required to take action and remove all information until such a time that we could get clarifying information. I don't recommend you ever make statements online that you are underage when you're not, whether it be a joke or not, *anywhere on the Internet*. It is just an incredibly bad idea.

At this time, I've restored all of your posts and comments to your new profile, which will also restore any reputation from them and re-award any badges you are still eligible for over time.

Comment: Thanks so much, @animuson - lesson learned and apologies to you for putting this burden of work on your head (but thanks all the same for doing it). There seem to be a few pieces of reputation missing. Last time I checked (last night GMT) I had over 1,200 reputation. The obvious omission seems to be a couple of 200 point bounties from Secespitus on questions I answered. Annoyingly I can't find the questions now, but I'm sure Secespitus would be happy to confirm.

Comment: An example of the bounties is [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/36165/23159), which can also be seen in the [timeline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/36165/timeline). [Second one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/36163/23159).  CC: @robertcday

Comment: Found one @animuson: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/30820/can-i-publish-a-book-containing-content-licensed-under-the-gnu-free-documentatio/36165#36165

Comment: And another @animuson: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/24472/can-i-publish-my-book-in-the-russian-language-with-advertising-and-selling-onlin/36163#36163

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it, @Secespitus :)

Comment: @robertcday I've honestly no idea why those wouldn't get reincorporated into your account - I don't see anything obvious that would suggest they're not. Will have someone look into it.

Comment: @animuson So that would seem to leave me a little short still. I can account for 790+400=1190 and should have 1212+?+155=1367 which leaves me down by at least 177. The ? varies according to when my user was deleted - the 1212 would have been from just before that and I had some points awarded between deletion and the end of the day. Sorry to moan on. :(

Comment: @robertcday It's hard to track down where any discrepancies might've been, because deletions are destructive by nature (and underage deletions the *most* destructive). E.g. if you ever suggested any edits, those can't be reconnected after the fact (only posts and comments get reconnected), so any reputation from them would've just been lost.

Comment: @animuson thanks for your work on this.  In case this helps, I had posts moved from one account to another (on a different site, not here) a few years ago, and my bounties came through.  I don't know if that was a separate thing that Tim had to do; they were there when he showed me the results.

Comment: Hi, @animuson - any news on the missing bounties? Is it possible to check if they were added back to Secespitus' account?

Comment: Hi, @Secespitus - when my account was deleted, were the 400 bounty points credited back to your account? Sorry to keep banging on about this.

Comment: @robertcday No, but I would say that's intended. Bounties are deducted the moment you place the bounty on a question and they can only be refunded by a moderator during the bounty period. The bounty served it's purpose of increasing the visibility of the question and therefore I shouldn't get the rep back. No idea why you don't get the rep though.

Comment: Anything you can do to help me out here, @Monica?

Comment: @robertcday It needs a developer to fix. Essentially, when a profile is deleted, any bounties awarded to them are changed so that `TargetUserId = null`, but reassociating posts manually does not change that TargetUserId back to the user. It just leaves it null, so the system doesn't think it belongs to you despite it being on your post.

Comment: Thanks, @animuson. How do I get in touch with a developer please? :)

Comment: @robertcday Someone is already aware of it. I can't tell you when it will actually be fixed though.

Comment: Thanks again, @animuson, so long as I know someone is looking at it. ;)

Comment: @animuson - a week later and nothing has happened - can you give whoever is fixing this another nudge please? Or alternatively, tell me who they are so that I don't have to bother you with this? Thanking you kindly. :)